# How is Rachel's sister Zelda related to a devil beyond the pet cemetery?

Tags: pet-sematary-2019

In *Pet Sematary* (2019), dead Zelda haunts her sister Rachel throughout the movie. But How is Rachel's sister Zelda related to devil beyond the pet cemetery?

Comment: I haven't see the movie.  Your question would be better if it included aquote from the movie or something establishing that Zelda was in some way "related" to a devil beyond the pet cemetery.  In its present state your question only establishes that Zelda is related to Rachel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rachel is facing death dilemmas which makes her repressed (death related) memories return to haunt her.

She encounter with death dilemma when she was left alone with her [dying sister](https://stephenking.fandom.com/wiki/Zelda_Goldman)

> **Rachel was left alone to care for her sister Zelda** which was usual. When Rachel began feeding her sister, Zelda started choking and her back and neck began to twist. As **Rachel watched in horror, Zelda finally succumbed to death** from her disease. Rachel then started to run downstairs, screaming "Zelda's dead!" repeatedly as the next door neighbors came and wondered what was going on. Rachel recalls when telling this story to her husband Louis, that her neighbors thought she was crying **but she was actually laughing**.

This helps you to understand her state of mind and thoughts about returning someone from the dead